# Как задать в constructor для каждого react-компонента Product своё начальное состояние?

Tags: reactjs

```
const products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      ...
    },
];
```

Я создал компонент ProductList, который содержит 3 компонента Product:

```
class ProductList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        const productComponents = products.map((product) => (
            <Product 
                 key = {'product-' + product.id}
                 id = {product.id}
                 ...
            />
        ));
        return ( 
            <ul className="holder-list row">
                {productComponents}
            </ul> 
        );
    }
}

class Product extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return(..)
    }
}
```

Я хочу установить начальное значение this.state для каждого Product разное.

Например:

для Product с id:1 - `this.state={color: blue}`,

для Product с id:2 - `this.state={color: yellow}`,

для Product с id:3 - `this.state={color: red}`.

Как я могу сделать что-то подобное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указываете поле `color` в своем массиве:

```
const products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      color: 'blue',
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      color: 'yellow',
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      color: 'red'
      ...
    },
];
```

Передаете `color` как свойство компонента

```
class ProductList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        const productComponents = products.map((product) => (
            <Product 
                 key = {'product-' + product.id}
                 id = {product.id}
                 color = {product.color} // Передаете color в компонент
                 ...
            />
        ));
        return ( 
            <ul className="holder-list row">
                {productComponents}
            </ul> 
        );
    }
}
```

В конструкторе задаете начальный state из props

```
class Product extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // В конструкторе задаете начальный state из props
        this.state = {
            color: props.color
        };
    }

    render() {
        return(..)
    }
}
```